# Supposedly 'Satoshi' was found in Australia… is there any way to verify this?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto

So far I can't tell what's true about all this.  It also seems like it'd be easy for someone to claim to be the pseudonymous creator of Bitcoin.  I've only seen information about this from main stream sources.  Does anyone know anything beyond the current main-stream narrative?

Comment: Proof that (at least part of) the story doesn't check out:  https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/3w027x/dr_craig_steven_wright_alleged_satoshi_by_wired/cxslii7

Comment: I read that his home and office were searched by the Australian Tax Office, where did you read that he was arrested?

Answer (score 0):

If someone purporting to be 'Satoshi Nakamoto' wanted to prove it, he/she could do so by signing a message using one of the same signing keys that 'Satoshi Nakamoto' used to sign one of his early messages during the release of bitcoin.  Or, he/she could announce that they will make a bitcoin payment from an address believed to belong to 'Satoshi Nakamoto' to some other address, then actually do so.

Comment: AFAIK Satoshi never signed any message with his key.

Comment: There appears to be conflicting information about this.  See the following Reuters article (http://www.reuters.com/article/us-australia-bitcoin-stakes-idUSKBN0TS1FQ20151209), where it says, "...or signing a message with one of the encryption keys used in emails known to have been written by Nakamoto ...".  On the other hand, https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Nakamoto states that he has a PGP key which was never used.  Either way, he could confirm his identitiy, if he wanted to, by signing a message using his PGP key, whether that key was used previously or not.

Comment: AFAIK SN had a pgp key on one of his profiles, but never encrypted any of his correspondence. Not sure what Reuter's source would be as they don't elaborate that point in the linked article.

Answer (score -2):

I'm literally just reading the [Gizmodo piece](http://gizmodo.com/this-australian-says-he-and-his-dead-friend-invented-bi-1746958692) as well. This piece is based off of a month long investigation where they've done some really good journalistic reporting. Highly recommended.

Comment: Bitcoin.SE. is not a place for discussion, but a question and answer site. Please use answers to address the question post. If you want to discuss Bitcoin, you may join us in [Chat] once you gain a little more reputation, or perhaps want to prefer other platforms.